# save table for later use in "variable"

Tags: lua, lua-table

> Is it possible to "save" a table with multiple sub-tables into a
>   variable and reuse it in, say, a for loop?
>
> somewhat along this:
>
> ```
> x = table1.table2
> for a, b in pairs (x)
> ...
> end
> ```

So, this is basically irrelevant, since it works exactly the way it is.
But: same question, except now:

```
x = table1.table2
y = x
for a, b in pairs (y)
...
end
```

I would need y to be recognized as a table.

Thanks again

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If `table1.table2` is a table, sure you can save it to `x` and use it later.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, just knowing that helped me figuring it out myself.

i have to declare x={} first

Comment: @Abjatar No, you don't.

Comment: Do you mean a "deep copy"?

Comment: hm... then it's not clear to me why it suddenly works...
a deep copy would be the brute force method I guess.

Comment: anyhow, for some inexplicable reason it didn't work before, although I don't think I did anything differently. thanks for the feedback though

Comment: The only thing you can "declare" in Lua is that a variable is `local`.